# LinkedList of LinkedList with recursion - loop issue

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have a List of Lists structure and a recursive function called **tree**. In the following code it NEVER reaches the `current == null` statement so it will run forever.

If I cannot use `null`, what is the solution?

```
private void tree(LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> partitions, LinkedList<String> part)
{
    LinkedList<String> current = findBiggerPartitionContained(partitions, part);
    if (current == null) {
        return;
    }
    tree(partitions, current);
}

private LinkedList<String> findBiggerPartitionContained(LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> partitions, LinkedList<String> part)
{
    LinkedList<String> max = new LinkedList<>();

    boolean flag = false;
    for (LinkedList<String> item : partitions) {
        if (item.size() > max.size() && part.containsAll(max)) {
            max = item;
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    if (!flag)
        return null;
    flag = false;
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Judging by your code, it should be `current.isEmpty()` instead of `current==null`

Comment: I just tried with isEmpty, but nothing changed.

Comment: Fine case for a debugger

Comment: I am confused, should you change you condition into "part.containsAll(item))" instead?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time `flag` will be `true` because your condition tests `item.size() > max.size()`, and `max` is initialized with an empty list. When `max` is empty, the expression `part.containsAll(max)` will be `true` as well, which leads to unexpected results.

In order to fix this, you can use this in `findBiggerPartitionContained`:

```
if (item.size() > max.size() && item.containsAll(part)) {
    max = item;
    flag = true;
}
```

And this in `tree`:

```
if (current.equals(part)) {
    return;
} else {
    tree(partitions, current);
}
```

If I have understood correctly, you're looking for the biggest list in `partitions` which contains `part`. Maybe the following is less error prone and more readable:

```
List<String> result = partitions.stream().filter(list -> list.containsAll(part))
                                         .max(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size))
                                         .orElse(null);
```

You can test it with this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
List<String> p0 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
List<String> p1 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
List<String> p2 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d"));
List<String> p3 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "e", "d"));
List<List<String>> partitions = Arrays.asList(p0, p1, p2, p3);

List<String> part = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "e"));

List<String> result = partitions.stream().filter(list -> list.containsAll(part))
                                         .max(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size))
                                         .orElse(null);

System.out.println(result);
```

Bear in mind that this may returns `null` to handle absent [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)s.